Can I add a mandatory keyword in AJV?
I'm building an API which can consume schema definitions which then get validated using ajv.validateSchema(). I want to add a mandatory keyword 'sortIndex' to my meta-schema validation. It needs to be a positive integer. Here's what I have:
ajv.addKeyword({
  keyword: 'sortIndex',
  schemaType: 'number',
  code(cxt: KeywordCxt) {
    const { schema } = cxt;
    cxt.fail(_`!(${_`${schema} > 0 && Number.isInteger(${schema})`})`);
  },
  error: {
    message: () => 'keyword "sortIndex" must be a positive integer'
  }
});

I have two questions now:

Can I make this keyword required in all properties in my schema?
I noticed the meta-schema validation kicks in only after I try to use compile -> validate on some content. Can I validate that the sortIndex keyword is missing during the ajv.validateSchema() check?

